# Site Title appearing twice on live site

Tags: templates, title

My [site](http://www.superlogical.net) [template](http://wpshower.com/themes/sight/)'s header.php file has the following:

`<title><?php wp_title ( '|', true,'right' ); ?></title>`

Why does this produce the site title twice on each page?

Comment: Do you have any SEO plugins running? they often play with the title without you asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two different SEO plugins: Yoast and All in One. Not a good idea. One of them is doubling up the title tag on single post pages.

Comment: In my plugins admin page, Yoast is not listed.

There is a wordpress-seo folder in wp-content\plugins, but no mention of Wordpress-SEO in the plugins admin page either.

Comment: Look at your page source: see Yoast and All in One SEO both loading? It's a broken theme (with broken English on the theme developer's site describing the SEO features, among others.) Ask the developer or look at the code yourself.